# How to implement smooth scrolling in vue js with different components?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to implement smooth scrolling in Vue with different components in it.  Like About.vue is the main component and AboutHeader.vue and AboutContent.vue are sub-components inside About.vue.

The AboutHeader.vue

```
<template>
     <div>
        <h1> About Heading</h1>
        <a href="#content">content</a>
     </div>
</template>
```

The AboutContent.vue

```
<template>
      <div>
         <h2> About Content</h2>
       </div>
</template>
```

About.vue file

```
<template>
  <div>
      <AboutHeader/>
      <AboutContent id="content"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

The scrolling on click of anchor tag is working but it is not smooth scrolling,
I have tried using vue2-smooth-scroll but it is not working.

I have put this inside my main.js file.

```
import VueSmoothScroll from 'vue2-smooth-scroll'
Vue.use(VueSmoothScroll)
```

and inside the AboutHeader.vue file

```
<a href="#content" v-smooth-scroll></a>
```

Comment: did you set `duration` delay?

Comment: oops silly mistake... thanks man I did not see the duration part  `Vue.use(VueSmoothScroll, {
  duration: 400,
  updateHistory: false,
})` I put this in and it worked